# AndroidStudio : Cannot resolve symbol MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest

I got an error "Cannot resolve symbol MainActivity" on this code.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"          //here
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="MainActivity"
                android:scheme="callback" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Needless to say , MainActivity inherits Activity and package name is correct too.

Why?

Thank you

Here's an image of the directory structure.

[image: Snapshot of the directory structure]

Comment: What does your package structure look like? Where is MainActivity in that structure?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your directory structure within android studio

Comment: I tried writing my package structure "com.example.fovoapp.MainActivity" but this error was not fixed.

Comment: This is my directory structure.

http://www.fastpic.jp/images.php?file=4073568203.png

Answer (score 20):

It's possible that your 'src' directory isn't set as a source directory?

Your IDE seems to be seeing your com.example.fovoapp as a simple directory structure instead of a package.  Also looking at your linked image, the little "J" on the java files tells me that also.  When a java file is set as source usually it shows up as a Class "C".

I could be wrong but make sure you set your src directory as source and that should fix the issue.

Comment: @MiguelLavigne please explain how to set your src director as source.

Answer (score 12):

package name on AndroidManifest.xml file and your classes must be same.

AndroidManifest.xml header:

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   package="com.ahmet.currencies">
```

Code:

```
package com.ahmet.currencies;

import ...;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {}
```

Comment: Packages are mainly handled by Gradle

Answer (score 3):

**Clean Caches**

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you use the wrong path for the src directory.
It should be in the path : `./yourApp/src/main` and not `./yourApp/src/androidTest`
You can move it manually.

Answer (score 2):

project structure, right click on src folder->Mark directory as-> sources root.

Now your mainactivity.java file with 'j' symbol to change to 'c' symbol.

The error was that the project did not have a valid source folder from where it could look for the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

In your **build.gradle** file add the following.

```
android {
     sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/<YOUR DIRECTORY NAME>'
        }
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set your compatible  api level. i also same the face error so i set my api level to 23 in file-> project structure-> app-> flavour -> target sdk version

Comment: You have to post this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @cod-e-rection why? It is an answer

Comment: @Zoe yes but in this case it was not close to the question.

Comment: @cod-e-rection except it is, and it does answer the question for OP, which does make this an answer.