# Android Studio: Android Manifest unable to resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported my android Eclipse project into Android Studio 1.0. The import ignored all of my source code files, so I have manually added them to the project. The error that I am getting is found on all of the activity names found in my AndroidManifest.xml file. For example:

```
<activity android:name="com.company.myapp.beforelogin.InitialActivity"></activity>
```

The AndroidManifest is unable to resolve the symbols "beforelogin" and "InitialActivity". I have read here ([AndroidStudio : Cannot resolve symbol MainActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041104/androidstudio-cannot-resolve-symbol-mainactivity)) that Android Studio doesn't recognize my code as source code. So I tried this ([How to get Android Studio to recognize file as source (test)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927447/how-to-get-android-studio-to-recognize-file-as-source-test)) to add my directory as a sourceSet in my build.gradle file, but it didn't work. My project structure looks like this:

```
-app
    -src
        -build.gradle
        -main
            -res
            -com
            -AndroidManifest.xml
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `com/` in your structure refers to the root package of your Java source, create a `java/` directory as a peer of `res/` (i.e., a child of `main/`) and move `com/` into `java/`.

Comment: I was just about to take this question down because I fixed it with the exact same solution that you suggested. I didn't realize it was a necessity to have :) Thank you for the reply :)